# How to remove all white space from the beginning or end of a string?

Tags: c#, string, trim, removing-whitespace

How can I remove all white space from the beginning and end of a string?

Like so:

`"hello"` returns `"hello"`
`"hello   "` returns `"hello"`
`" hello   "` returns `"hello"`
`" hello world   "` returns `"hello world"`

Answer (score 547, accepted):

[`String.Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) returns a string which equals the input string with all [white-spaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) trimmed from start *and* end:

```
"   A String   ".Trim() -> "A String"
```

`String.TrimStart()` returns a string with white-spaces trimmed from the start:

```
"   A String   ".TrimStart() -> "A String   "
```

`String.TrimEnd()` returns a string with white-spaces trimmed from the end:

```
"   A String   ".TrimEnd() -> "   A String"
```

None of the methods modify the original string object.

(In some implementations at least, if there are no white-spaces to be trimmed, you get back the same string object you started with:

`csharp> string a = "a";
csharp> string trimmed = a.Trim();
csharp> (object) a == (object) trimmed;
returns true`

I don't know whether this is guaranteed by the language.)

Comment: ⁺¹ for the MS definition of whitespace. I met a weird behavior that `.TrimEnd()` doesn't work *(for non-breaking space character)*, but in the end is just that the character not listed in documentation.

Comment: There are numerous ways to trim strings, and [quite a few are bench-marked.](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-trim-strings) Still, I like .Trim() as being the quickest to write and easiest to read.

Comment: Maybe it is usefull to know this: If you have multiply lines like in a TextArea. And you press the enter key, you get something like: `"    A String \r\n     "`   `.Trim()` does recognize this as a space too.

Comment: @NashCarp: That´s because \r and \n are also [whitespace characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 25):

take a look at [`Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) which returns a new string with whitespace removed from the beginning and end of the string it is called on.

Answer (score 22):

```
string a = "   Hello   ";
string trimmed = a.Trim();
```

`trimmed` is now `"Hello"`

Answer (score 18):

use the `String.Trim()` function.

```
string foo = "   hello ";
string bar = foo.Trim();

Console.WriteLine(bar); // writes "hello"
```

Answer (score 13):

Use `String.Trim` method.

Answer (score 11):

`String.Trim()` removes all whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.
To remove whitespace inside a string, or normalize whitespace, use a Regular Expression.

Answer (score 4):

`Trim()`
Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current string.
`Trim(Char)`
Removes all leading and trailing instances of a character from the current string.
`Trim(Char[])` Removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current string.

Look at the following example that I quoted from Microsoft's documentation page.

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '*', ' ', '\''};
string banner = "*** Much Ado About Nothing ***";
string result = banner.Trim(charsToTrim);
Console.WriteLine("Trimmmed\n   {0}\nto\n   '{1}'", banner, result);

// The example displays the following output:
//       Trimmmed
//          *** Much Ado About Nothing ***
//       to
//          'Much Ado About Nothing'
```