# enter space at the end of value cause error

Tags: c#, regex

Im having following reg-ex which is working OK, the only thing is 
if user type any value which is valid and press than spaces I got error,
how can I avoid the space at the end of the values?

```
@"^[a-z\d][\da-z-.]*[a-z\s\d]$",
```

Comment: You want the regex to not match if there is a space just before the end?

Comment: Are a single "a" or "a." (for example) valid (with or without spaces at the end)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-z\d][\da-z-.]*[a-z\s\d][\s]*$
```

Use this if you want to accept any amount of whitespace characters at the end (small `S`).

```
^[a-z\d][\da-z-.]*[a-z\s\d][\S]*$
```

Use this if you don't want to accept strings with white spaces at the end (capital `S`).

Or you can also use the `Trim` function after you matched it with the unchanged regex.

Comment: Oops.. I think your answer is better Xb

Comment: Your second pattern is false, since `\S*` can match an empty string and `[a-z\s\d]` can match a space.

Answer (score 0):

simply using

String.Trim();

```
 string foo = "   hello ";
 string bar = foo.Trim();

 Console.WriteLine(bar); // writes "hello"
```

See more:[How to remove all white spaces from the start or end of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381952/how-automatically-remove-all-white-spaces-start-or-end-in-a-string)

Comment: I cant use trim since I use the validation in the model,there is no other way with regex?

Comment: @shopiaT see BedFord answer