# Trying to replace all white space with a single space

Tags: c#, regex, whitespace

My program is a file validation utility. I have to read in a format file and then parse out each line by a single space. But obviously, the person who wrote the format file may use tabs, or two spaces, or any form of whitespace, and I'm looking for some code to do that. I've tried this:

```
public static string RemoveWhitespace(this string line)
{
    try
    {
        return new Regex(@"\s*").Replace(line, " ");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return line;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming this is wrong. What should I do?

Comment: If you are going to do this lots of times you might want to store the construct the Regex object beforehand. A private static readonly would do. Then you avoid the creation of the regex engine everytime you are going to replace a line.

Comment: @Skurmedel: Or just use the built-in static `Regex.Replace` method.

Comment: @LukeH: I think you missed my point. There's a reason why you can preconstruct the regex objects, and not only for easy reusability. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx "Static vs Instance methods". Granted, if he/she doesn't use 15 different regexes in his application there are probably no problem. But I don't know his/her application. That's why I said "might".

Comment: The static method caches a limited number of the most recently used patterns, so if you know that your application isn't doing anything else with Regex between calls then it's optimal. If you're doing this in a library, you might prefer your own static instance to be sure that the consuming application doesn't accidentally cause cache misses.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do this -

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str,@"\s+"," ");
```

where `str` is your string.

Comment: I really want to accept this as my answer but it just doesn't seem to work. It just keeps throwing an exception. Also, just a general question; in regards to Regex, does '\s' just mean whitespace?

Comment: @New Start - Can you tell me what the error is? I hope you are using proper namespace right?

Comment: @New Start - '\s' matches white space character. check this - http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand

Comment: @New Start - I have tried this on my end. it Works fine. If you can tell what is your error, I can help you with that.

Comment: I was using proper namespace, yes! My problem was I was returning the original line instead of the edited line. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
input = input.Replace("\t", " ");

List<string> empties = new List<string>();
for (int i=input.Length - 1; i>1; i--)
{
    string spcs = "";
    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        spcs += " ";
    if (input.Contains(spcs))
        empties.Add(spcs);
}

foreach (string s in empties)
    input = input.Replace(s, " ");
```

Comment: That seems like a very inefficient way. Is it? What is its costs in terms of memory and execution time?