# How to remove extra space between two words using C#?

Tags: c#, string

How to remove extra space between two words using C#? Consider:

```
"Hello       World"
```

I want this to be manipulated as `"Hello World"`.

Comment: Do you mean you want it to become "HelloWorld"?

Comment: your strings ... Consider "Hello World" is the same here as "Hello World", do you mean "Hello     World"  -> "Hello World"
do you just want to remove or do you want to extract the space to?

Comment: Remember guys, HTML collapses spaces :)

Comment: oops~, does & nbsp; work on SO?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);     
tempo = regex.Replace(tempo, @" ");
```

or even:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\s+", " ");
```

both pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)

Comment: but this answer is a general "do it with reg ex" answer, not a specific C# answer... :)

Answer (score 17):

```
var text = "Hello      World";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can pass options to [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) to tell it to collapse consecutive separator characters, so you can write:

```
string expr = "Hello      World";
expr = String.Join(" ", expr.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "Hello      World";
Regex rex = new Regex(@" {2,}");

rex.Replace(text, " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    string str = "Hello       World";

    Regex exper=new Regex(@"\s+");
    Console.WriteLine(exper.Replace(str, @" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

**CLEAR EXTRA SPACES BETWEEN A STRING IN ASP. NET C#**

SUPPOSE: A NAME IS JITENDRA      KUMAR
AND I HAVE CLEAR SPACES BETWEEN NAME AND CONVERT THE STRING IN : JITENDRA KUMAR;
THEN FOLLOW THIS CODE:

```
 string PageName= "JITENDRA    KUMAR";
 PageName = txtEmpName.Value.Trim().ToUpper();
 PageName = Regex.Replace(PageName, @"\s+", " ");

 Output string Will be : JITENDRA KUMAR
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
string helloWorldString = "Hello    world";

while(helloWorldString.Contains("  "))
 helloWorldString = helloWorldString.Replace("  "," ");
```

Comment: `Replace` returns the new string, it doesn't mutate the current string. What you have is an infinite loop when `helloWorldString` has a double space.