# ASP.NET C# String.Split

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to split a string if there is a space between words.

For example:

```
"Blood Doner Jack Stv 240 o+"
```

When I split it using a single space it returns an array object with 6 items, but if I try it with the same set of text and there are 2 spaces in place of one it increase the array to 7:

```
"Blood  Doner Jack Stv 240 o+"
```

So I want to know how to remove split it with a double space as well as a single.

I know I can use Replace() with 2 spaces to 1 space but what if I have 3 or 4 spaces?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [overload of `String.Split` which takes a `StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx):

```
string[] bits = text.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Note that to avoid creating a char array on each call, you could use:

```
private static readonly char[] SplitSeparators = {' '};

...

string[] bits = text.Split(SplitSeparators,
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Good call on using readonly static variable to store the split characters.  This is often overlooked, but for the worst case, it can have a performance impact.

Answer (score 4):

just use  [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx):

```
 var s = "Blood  Doner Jack Stv 240 o+";
 var arr = s.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Or you can replace many spaces with one using Regexp, and than Split:

```
string str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx.Replace(s ,@"\s+"," ");
var arr = str.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove spaces:

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);     
tempo = regex.Replace(tempo, @" ");
```

Then you can split normally

[How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/206717/735864)

[How to remove extra space between two words using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4400550/735864)

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1 = "Blood  Doner Jack Stv 240 o+";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\s+");
string s2 = r.Replace(s1, @" ");
string[] s3 = s2.Split(' ');
```