# Splitting string variable on a space or 2 spaces in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string variable, which is basically 3 strings, separated by one space each.These 3 strings may vary in length.
Like

```
string line="XXX YY ZZ";
```

Now, it occassionally happens that my string variable `line`, consists of 3 strings, where the first and the second string are separated by 2 spaces, instead of one.

```
string line="XX  YY ZZ";
```

What I wanted to do is store the 3 strings in a string array.Like:

`string[] x` where `x[0]="XXX"` , `x[1]="YY"` , `x[2]="ZZ"`

I tried to use the Split function.

```
string[] allId = line.Split(' ');
```

It works for the first case, not for the second. Is there any neat, simple way to do this?

Comment: You could try using a regular expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4400550/1577396

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just remove empty strings from result:

```
var allId = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Beat me to it, You should always look and see if there are more overrides than the basic function signature.

Comment: @SheridanBulger +1, overloads often help

Comment: @hometoast, btw I think you need to create array of chars, when you use overload with split options

Comment: I always screw up my inline-array declarations. So I stick with `" ".ToCharArray()`.  #lazy  (and yes your'e right, I got the signature wrong. StringSplitOptions requires and array as first argument -- good catch.)

Answer (score 8):

Use Regex split. Why? Space is not the only character representing a space; there are tabs as well.

By using regex split with a `\s+` pattern, that operation will *consume* all space combinations even with a mixture of tabs and spaces, thus allowing text to be returned. Example

```
var result = Regex.Split("XX  YYY    ZZZ", @"\s+");

// "XX", "YYY", "ZZZ" returned in array
```

[image: Linqpad results image capture]

**Pattern Summary**

`\s`  means any non character, a space or tab.
`+`   after it says, I expect at least one, but more than one can be found.

So the `+` after the `\s` means that the regex processor will look for one or more spaces to split on as a match. Everything between the matches will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You use the split method with an extra parameter.

The `.split` method is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx).

The 2nd parameter `options` is of type `StringSplitOptions` and is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx).

The 2 possible values of this parameter are `StringSplitOptions.None` and `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

So, simply do:

```
string[] allId = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and you have want you want! Easy.