# how can i avoid counting double spaces as words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("[class^='count[']").each(function() {

        var elClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var minWords = 0;
        var maxWords = 0;
        var countControl = elClass.substring((elClass.indexOf('['))+1, elClass.lastIndexOf(']')).split(',');

        if(countControl.length > 1) {

            minWords = countControl[0];
            maxWords = countControl[1];

        } 

        else { maxWords = countControl[0]; }



        $(this).after('<div class="wordCount"><strong>0</strong> words so far</div>');

            if(minWords > 0) {
                                $(this).siblings('.wordCount').addClass('error');
                             }

        $(this).bind('keyup click blur focus change paste', function() {

            var numWords = jQuery.trim($(this).val()).split(' ').length;
                if($(this).val() === '') {
                        numWords = 0;
                    }

        $(this).siblings('.wordCount').children('strong').text(numWords);
            if(numWords < minWords || (numWords > maxWords && maxWords != 0)) {
                $(this).siblings('.wordCount').addClass('error');
                } 
                else {
                    $(this).siblings('.wordCount').removeClass('error');
                }

        });
    });
});
```

this script basically counts the spaces between words but if extra spaces are added it counts them as new words too...

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/creating-a-jquery-word-counter/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.split()` also accepts regular expressions. Try this:

```
var numWords = jQuery.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).length;
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove all double spaces with a Regex and then do your script. If there are no double spaces to find, it cannot count them.

This is an example in C#, but the same accounts for javascript: [How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)