# How to allow user to enter only ONE SPACE after each word?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, removing-whitespace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)

I have a TextBox in which user is going to enter search Criteria in TEXTBOX. Now, i want to prevent the user from entering **NOT MORE THAN ONE SPACE** *AFTER EACH WORD* in TEXTBOX. How to do it in C#.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your question tells us what you want to implement, but what is the actual business requirement? There are a couple of ways to approach this, of which restricting the user's entry is probably the hardest and most cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to do it via the server side you could do a simple regex that would replace any double spaces with a singular space

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);     
MyTextBox.Text= regex.Replace(MyTextBox.Text, @" ");
```

If you wan to do it on the client side you can still use the same regex but do it on JavaScript and fire it on the onBlur event

Comment: Thanks@John Mitchell this is exactly right what i want...! Thank u!