# Multiple replace

Tags: c#, replace

Have:

```
"a__b_c_____d__e_f__"
```

Need:

```
"a_b_c_d_e_f_"
```

ie: Replace all the `"___"` substrings (1 or more underscores) with `"_"` (single underscore) *without loops*.

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Think recursion.

Comment: I really don't know any nice solution. That's why asked. Maybe regexp...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/206717/416627)

Comment: there will be at least one loop somewhere

Comment: nope. look at the accepted answer. the only loops inside the `Regex` implementation

Comment: Jeez.  Replace one or more _'s in a row with a single _.  This is trivial in Regex.  Like `_+` trivial.  (edit) oh, and look at the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a regular expression, e.g.

```
var input = "a__b_c_____d__e_f__";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "_+", "_");
```

Comment: +1, I was about to link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/206946/416627) with the same suggested modification.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using RegularExpressions as follow

```
string str = "a__b_c_____d__e_f__";
string newStr = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "_{2,}", "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var cleanString = Regex.Replace("a__b_c_____d__e_f__", "(_)+", "$1");
```

Answer (score -1):

This should get you started.

```
cat file | perl -e "s/\_+/\_/g"
```

Comment: +1 .. because it's same same regular expression and suggests that the poster continues the thinking .. although perhaps should just be a comment.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to go about solving the issue, but I'm a little uncertain what you mean by "without loops"...

obviously you could use a loop such as:

```
while (myString.contains("__"))
    myString.replace("__", "_");
```

I think though that this is what you are saying you're trying to avoid... the catch is though, that I don't believe there is a solution that doesn't involve loops somewhere. The .contains method, as well as the .replace method both use loops in their implementations. To clarify, the following code would also work:

```
string outputStr = "";
bool underscore = false;
for(int i = 0; i < myString.length; ++i)
{
    if (myString[i] == '_')
    {
        if (underscore == false)
            outputStr += myString[i];
        underscore = true;
    }else outputStr += myString[i];
}
```

As you can see, this only uses one loop. While this is more efficient, (You would probably want to use a StringBuilder instead of a string for the outputStr variable, if efficiency were an issue) the point is that if you need to look through a string, you're going to have to use a loop, whether it's you who writes the loop or whether you are calling some other method that does it for you.