# Searching strings irrespective of whitespace

Tags: algorithm

I have an ArrayList of phrases containing `"a"`, `"b"`, `"ab"`, `"ab c"`, `"ab cd"`.
The input might be `"ab c"` or `"ab    c"`. In either cases it should match with `"ab c"` from the ArrayList. I need an algorithm for it.

Comment: Have you tried thinking about it?

Comment: "ab c" or "ab c"? What's the difference..

Comment: @XiaoJia: There is actually more space in the raw text between ab and c, but it's not showing.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, I have thought of using String tokenizer but after some research i found out that the problem of whitespaces between strings could not be solved.

Comment: String.equals("another string")

Comment: This might be what you need:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c

Comment: Why not strip whitespace from both sides and compare? In javascript: `s1.replace(/\s/g, '') === s2.replace(/\s/g, '')`

Comment: @cda01 I think you did not understand the problem. I cannot remove the whitespaces rather I want the strings to get compared regardless of the whitespaces between them.

Comment: @SuneetaSingh, You don't need to remove whitespaces from actual data, only when you compare two strings, you make a local copy of both of the candidate, eliminate whitespaces from them and compare those local copies.

Comment: @SuneetaSingh do something like `if (phrase.Replace(" ", "") == input.Replace(" ", "") ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what language you're using, but the simplest pseudocode is:

```
f(string inString, ArrayList<string> list):
    string s = inString.removeAllWhitespace();
    foreach (string s2 in list):
        string lString = s2.removeAllWhitespace();
        if (s.equals(lString))
            return true

    return false
```

If you want it to be faster, try something like this:

```
f(string inString, ArrayList<string> list):
    foreach (string s in list):
        i1 = 0
        i2 = 0
        while (i1 < inString.length && i2 < s.length):
            if (iswhitespace(inString[i1])):
                i1++
            else if (iswhitespace(s[i2])):
                i2++
            else if (inString[i1] == s[i2]):
                i1++
                i2++
            else:
                continue foreach

        # account for trailing whitespace in both strings
        while (i1 < inString.length):
            if (!iswhitespace(inString[i1])):
                break
            i1++
        while (i2 < s.length):
            if (!iswhitespace(s[i2])):
                break
            i2++

        # strings are equal if we reached the end of both without
        # finding different characters (ignoring whitespace)
        if (i1 == inString.length && i2 == s2.length):
            return true
    return false
```

This will go iterate through each string with unique indices, incrementing when either whitespace is found or a match. If the characters don't match, the string is rejected and the outer loop is continued.

This pseudocode is untested, but should give you an idea of how to do it. I recommend going the remove whitespace route. It's much simpler code, not too slow, and gives the reader very obvious clues as to what you're trying to do.

In most languages, strings are immutable, so doing this replacement won't affect the strings in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

What you're really asking is how to replace the multiple spaces with a single space. This might be what you need:[See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool hacked_compare(const string& s, const string& t){
    string::const_iterator si = s.begin(), ti = t.begin();
    while (si != s.end() && ti != t.end() && (isspace(*si) || isspace(*ti))){
        // ignore all spaces leading to next char.
        while (si != s.end() && isspace(*si))
            si++;
        while (ti != t.end() && isspace(*ti))
            ti++;
        // check for equality of two chars.
        if (*si != *ti)
            return false;
        // keep going through both strings.
        si++;
        ti++;
    }
    //if we got this far then the strings were "equivalent" or empty.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did minimal testing, but this should do it, and you won't need to copy any strings or even create temporary copies of local strings.  It should be big O(n) so its performance is as good as you can get.