# Im trying to make this code recursive but for some reason it doesnt work

Tags: c

I'm trying to make this code recursive but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
void compress_spaces(char *str)
{
    char *dst = str;

    for (; *str; ++str) {
            *dst++ = *str;
            if (isspace(*str)) {
                    do ++str; while (isspace(*str));
                    --str;
            }
    }
    *dst = 0;
}
```

*EDIT:*
I tried this:

```
void text_r(char *str)
{
    char *dst = str;

            if(*str=='\0')return ;
            *dst++ = *str;
            if (isspace(*str)) {
                    do ++str; while (isspace(*str));
                    --str;
            }//Missing brace from orig is this ok?
          return text_r(str++);
}
```

Didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any recursion in there ?

Comment: I don't see any recurssion here. Show us the code that is not working and say **what** is not working in it.

Comment: yea, its *not* recursive. You need a call to `compress_spaces()` for that.

Comment: it is a code to change multiple spaces to one space

Comment: a recursive function must call itself, so where is the "compress_spaces" call?

Comment: Recursion: See recursion, oops, there is none...

Comment: To change multiple consecutive spaces by one, try a regular expression like this: /  +/ /g (2 spaces before the +)

Comment: i know it's not recursive i tried to make it recursive but it didnt work here is my try >>>void text_r(char *str)
{
        char *dst = str;

                if(*str=='\0')return ;
                *dst++ = *str;
                if (isspace(*str)) {
                        do ++str; while (isspace(*str));
                        --str;
              return text_r(str++);
}

Comment: Did somebody mistaken re-entrant with recursive?

Comment: @user2042145 ouch. update *your question* with that please. don't post  question code in a comment.

Comment: i updated it ! any idea ppl

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to make it recursive? Is the program too fast or does it use too little memory?

Comment: @Lundin LOL. best question I've seen on SO today.

Comment: im trying to help my friend who is taking the course in C language i wrote the code but he needs a recursive one

Comment: @user2042145 you can start by telling your friend this is a *really* lousy question to try and teach students recursion, and his prof needs to think of better examples. This task is *ideal* for an iterative solution; recursion honestly just makes it muddy.

Comment: The most common argument for using recursion seems to be "I'm trying to understand recursion". Rather than learning of how recursion works, you should perhaps focus on understanding what it is good for.

Comment: Closed so cannot answer, but you could `void recur(char *str, char *out) {
  if (*str!=' ' || str[1]!=' ') *out++ = *str;
  if (*str) recur(str+1, out);
}` Called with *str* and *out* being the same pointer (if you want) to a writable memory area (eg. `char str[] = "...";`)

Comment: @ring0 check this link please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702877/recursive-form-of-changing-multiple-spaces-to-one-space

Answer (score 1):

Your dst pointer is not the same pointer in the recursively called function, pass it as an argument instead.

```
void text_r(char *dst, char *str) {
  if (*str=='\0')
    return;
  *dst++ = *str;
  if (isspace(*str)
    while (isspace(*str++));
  else
    ++str;
  return text_r(dst, str);
}
```

Why you want to do this with recursion is completely beyond me by the way, it only wastes time and space.

Comment: The code works perfectly ! try it ur self

Comment: @WhozCraig, user2042145 yeah sorry, wasn't reading the dst initialization correctly, sorry about that. The problem is still the same though, you reinitialize the dst pointer every time the function is called which messes up your algorithm, pull it onto the stack to fix it.

Comment: That would defiantly work ! but here i trying to help some student and the task is to create a function with only the string in the stack ! i know that is kind of stupid but i cant do it :P

Comment: That won't work with this design.

Comment: any ideas ? hints maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c) may helps you. It resolves your problem with a regular expression