# recursive form of changing multiple spaces to one space

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Im trying to make this code recursive but for some reason it doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702016/im-trying-to-make-this-code-recursive-but-for-some-reason-it-doesnt-work)

Im trying to write program using RECURSION to change multiple spaces to one space can anyone help ? 
example "a_______b" changes to "a_b" 
it is a task that im trying to do for a long time ! can anyone help ?

here i tried this but i think the design doesnt work for recursion

```
void text_r(char *str)
{
    char *dst = str;

            if(*str=='\0')return ;
            *dst++ = *str;
            if (isspace(*str)) {
                    do ++str; while (isspace(*str));
                    --str;
            }
          return text_r(str++);
}
```

i wrote the code without recursion but i have problem in converting it

void compress_spaces(char *str)
{
        char *dst = str;

```
    for (; *str; ++str) {
            *dst++ = *str;
            if (isspace(*str)) {
                    do ++str; while (isspace(*str));
                    --str;
            }
    }
    *dst = 0;
```

}

Comment: Maybe you can describe what you did and why it failed?

Comment: Asking the same question twice is not going to solve your problem.

Comment: if you cant help maybe others can , thanks for trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive version (avoiding any iterative part, like *while*) using the same pointer, given twice as argument

```
void recur(char *str, char *out) {
  if (*str!=' ' || str[1]!=' ') *out++ = *str;
  if (*str) recur(str+1, out);
}
```

Recursive version having only one param

```
void recur(char *str) {
  static char *out = NULL;
  if (out == NULL) out = str;
  if (*str!=' ' || str[1]!=' ') *out++ = *str;
  if (*str) recur(str+1);
}
```

Iterative version

```
void iter(char *str) {
  char *out = str;
  do {
    if (*str!=' ' || str[1]!=' ') *out++ = *str;
  } while (*str++);
}
```

To be called like

```
  char str[] = "   abc  d e  f   ";
  // either recursive
  recur(str, str);
  // or iterative
  iter(str);
```

Comment: that was extremely  helpful ! any suggestions of how to make it more useful ! like just calling the string once in the stack ?

Comment: What do you mean by *calling the string once in the stack*?

Comment: im mean calling it like this recur(str) not recur(str,str)

Comment: Added the one param recursive func

Answer (score 0):

Not the best method but try something along these lines

```
char* remove_space(char *str)
{
    char *dst = str;

    while(*str!=' ' ||*str !='\0')
        *dst++ = *str;
    if (isspace(*str)) {
            do ++str; while (isspace(*str));
            --str;
    }
  return strcat(dst,remove_space(str++));
}
```

Idea being that you find characters and store them in a string and when you reach a space you store the first one and ignore the rest. Then you can send the new string to the function again. and you return the result concatinated with the new string

P.S. Probably the code above will not compile but it should give you a good idea on how to approach this.

Elaborating a bit:

make a function which saves all characters till a space, then ignores all consecutive spaces and sends the remaining string to a function which returns a clean string back. then it joins the two strings to make a bigger clean string.

Comment: the idea was clear for me i even wrote it with out recursion but when i wanted to change it to a recursive way it didnt work im not so good in recursion , maybe i can post the code if that helps ?

Comment: if you have a working code with iteration post that...

Comment: you should add the char *dst as an argument to the function and not initialize it in the loop then it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation. I replace each band of multiple spaces by keeping of the last space character and make a remove that band when a nonspace character is found

```
void reduce(String s, int curIndex, int lastSpaceIndex)
    if (lastSpaceIndex != -1)
        if s[curIndex] is not a space
            then replace substring from s[lastSpaceIndex, curIndex-1] by a space
        else
            reduce(s, curIndex+1, lastSpaceIndex);
    else
        if s[curIndex] is not a space
            then reduce(s, curIndex+1, -1)
        else
            reduce(s, curIndex+1, curIndex)
```

Comment: dont you think that using pointers for the current index would be better ? i have the idea but i cant put it all together in a good code ! check my previous code can you spot the mistake there ?