# How to write recursive function that copies a string to a location?

Tags: c

any ideas about how to write a  RECURSIVE function that gets 2 parameters :
first is an address d (a location of char).
second is a string.
The function copies the string s to a location starting at d.
The function returns d as a result ! 
can we do it without strcpy ?

```
    copy_r(char *s, char *d)
{
    *d = *s;
    if(*s)return copy_r(++s, ++d);
}
```

where is the mistake ? (found )
put still there is a problem ! what if the location d overlaps some location that is already occupied by s ?
this for example 
strcpy(p1, "abcdefghijklomopqrstuvwqyz"); printf(copy_r(p1, p1+10));doesnt work –

output should be  klomopqrstuvwqyz

Comment: Yes it can be done without `strcpy`, and it can be done recursively.

Comment: This is the same as asking "can `strcpy()` be implemented in C?", and of course the answer is yes.

Comment: Sure, it can be done... Have *you* tried anything yet?

Comment: assignment question? & yes, *Have you tried anything yet*?

Comment: any ideas how to write it recursively ? hints maybe

Comment: hint: look at the [2 lines recursive function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702877/recursive-form-of-changing-multiple-spaces-to-one-space/14704571#14704571) I wrote in your previous question... by modifying it *a bit* you have the result

Comment: im not so good at that im just trying to see some examples to practice ! any help will be appreciated

Comment: @user2042145 - Just try "recursive strcpy C" in Google, the first hit I see is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Mike *give a man an answer and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to google and you feed him for a lifetime*

Comment: @anishsane here is my try

Answer (score 1):

`where is the mistake`

Well, there isn't any mistake, this code sample works correctly... the only issue I see is that it doesn't work exactly as you expect. You mentioned you wanted it to `The function returns d as a result` and you don't have it doing that.

The code currently takes `s` and copies the contents into `d` so if you had something like:

```
char * str = "hello";
char * ptr = malloc(6);
copy_r(str, ptr);
// now ptr has "hello" too
```

Comment: will adding a halting condition like 
if(s=='\0') return d;
will it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Your copy logic is perfect. Just that you are not returning any value (d)...

This should work:

```
char* copy_r(char *s, char *d)
{
    *d = *s;
    if(*s)
      return copy_r(s + 1, d + 1 ) - 1 ; //-1 is to take care of d+1 part
    else
      return d;
}
```

sample usage:

```
int main(){
    char src[]="hello world";
    char dest[50];

    char* t=copy_r(src,dest);

    printf("%s\n%s\n",t,dest); //t==dest. thus you don't really have to return anything from the function.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks ! put still there is a problem ! what if the location d overlaps
some location that is already occupied by s ?

Comment: strcpy(p1, "abcdefghijklomopqrstuvwqyz");
printf(copy_r(p1, p1+10)); this for example doesnt work

Comment: So for this example, what is the expected output?

Comment: output is klomopqrstuvwqyz

Comment: & why do you think expectation `klomopqrstuvwqyz` is correct (read:appropriate/right)? this does not have copy of source...