# Remove a list of strings from a string - C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I have a list of stopwords that need to be removed from a string.

```
List<string> stopwordsList = stopwords.getStopWordList();
string text = PDF.getText();
foreach (string stopword in stopwordsList)
{
   text = text.Replace(stopword, "");
}
PDF.setText(text);
```

..in debug I can see the stopwordsList is being populated correctly, but it seems like the `text.Replace()` is having no effect whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: Note I have also tried `text.Replace()` on its own, rather than `text = text.Replace()`. Neither work.

Comment: what does the getText function return?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Have you debugged it and checked what stopword is in each iteration of the foreach loop? I'm pretty sure those are incorrect, because the code looks fine otherwise.

Comment: are you only checking the result of text from the PDF objects setText method?  the replace looks like it should work

Comment: Is it possible that your stopwords list strings and your text string from PDF are different cases? Like "morning" and "Morning"?

Comment: Could provide the sample values of text and stopwords ?

Comment: Could you try posting a sample of the actual data that you're working with?  I think a few people (including myself) have tested your code and it appears to do what you expect.

Comment: This looks all fine to me unless the `text` doesn't match with the values contains in the list. I think you might need to see [C# Case Insenstive String Replace](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10890/Fastest-C-Case-Insenstive-String-Replace)

Comment: What your stop words look like? Imagine that you want to remove "a" (indefinite article) in the text "A simple replace is as good as a mistake". If you just remove "a" with Replace you'll have "A simple replce is s good s  mistke" that's incorrect. It seems that you should use regular expressions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though i don't think there is anything wrong with your code, but i would do something like this.

```
string someText = "this is some text just some dummy text Just text";
List<string> stopwordsList = new List<string>() { "some", "just", "text" };    
someText = string.Join(" ", someText.Split().Where(w => !stopwordsList.Contains(w, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

you can ignore the `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` part if casing is important though.

> Note I have also tried text.Replace() on its own, rather than text = text.Replace()

you should know that Replace function returns string which should be handled if you want the updated string. so you are essentially doing it right now. i.e. `text = text.Replace()`

Comment: wondering the same. @huMptyduMpty

Comment: In the absence of any other input from the OP, I too am inclined to assume case sensitivity to be the culprit. By the way, I would use a Hashset<string> instead of a List<string> in case the stopwords list is significantly large.

Comment: By the way, your code assumes that the PDF source is like: "Now is the winter of our discontent, made glorious summer by this sun of York", and not "NowisthewinterofourdiscontentmadeglorioussummerbythissunofYork" .

Answer (score 2):

There is one catch, though... All previous solutions do not take into account word boundaries. For example, word 'hell' might be a bad word, but word 'hello' is perfectly valid. Also, replacement should be done only on full words otherwise you can get weird results.

Here is code that takes word boundaries into account:

```
var text = "Hello world, this is a great test!";
var badWords = new List<string>()
{
    "Hello", 
    "great"
};

var wordMatches = Regex.Matches(text, "\\w+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Index);

foreach (var m in wordMatches)
    if (badWords.Contains(m.Value))
        text = text.Remove(m.Index, m.Length);

Debug.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: nice anyway this work better ;) : text = text.Remove(m.Index, m.Length + 1);

Comment: Not always. You are assuming that there is a [space] after the word to be removed, but it could be also some kind of punctuation mark what gives a full meaning to sentence (period, question mark, exclamation, etc). It would be smarter to process string as in original answer and after that just remove duplicate spaces. There are a plenty samples how to do that. One is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)