# C# Console Word Wrap

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a string with newline characters and I want to wrap the words. I want to keep the newline characters so that when I display the text it looks like separate paragraphs. Anyone have a good function to do this? Current function and code below.(not my own function). The WordWrap function seems to be stripping out \n characters.

```
static void Main(string[] args){

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("E:/Adventure Story/Intro.txt");

        string intro = "";
        string line;

        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            intro += line;
            if(line == "")
            {
                intro += "\n\n";
            }
        } 
        WordWrap(intro);

public static void WordWrap(string paragraph)
    {
        paragraph = new Regex(@" {2,}").Replace(paragraph.Trim(), @" ");
        var left = Console.CursorLeft; var top = Console.CursorTop; var lines = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; paragraph.Length > 0; i++)
        {
            lines.Add(paragraph.Substring(0, Math.Min(Console.WindowWidth, paragraph.Length)));
            var length = lines[i].LastIndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (length > 0) lines[i] = lines[i].Remove(length);
            paragraph = paragraph.Substring(Math.Min(lines[i].Length + 1, paragraph.Length));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top + i); Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: add `\n` to the end of each line

Comment: Or `System.Enviroment.NewLine`

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're going to achieve. Provide your effort, even if written i pseudo-code.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I already have \n s in my string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Console.WriteLine() wrap words instead of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534318/make-console-writeline-wrap-words-instead-of-letters)

Comment: Well then i can't help much further as though that will solve your problem yet it doesn't so i should assume there's some error in your code, so if you would include your code it would much easier for us to help you :)

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I'm on my phone and I'll add the code later. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please? For example, could you add a screenshot of your output and a sketch / simulation of what you want it to look like? Is there a specific limitation on the line length or it has to wrap with screen resize? What is your output media? It sound like a console screen, but many console screens DO wrap the words by default. Do you want to wrap lines at the a specific width? Is it OK if it doesn't re-wrap when you resize the console window? Do you expect your text to be written out to other devices (printers, other screens, etc)?

Comment: @aiodintsov I've added the output. No, there's no limitations on line length and I don't care about screen resizing, only the initial printout. Console doesn't wrap by default. And no to the last question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a word wrap function that works by using regular expressions to find the places that it's ok to break and places where it must break. Then it returns pieces of the original text based on the "break zones". It even allows for breaks at hyphens (and other characters) without removing the hyphens (since the regex uses a zero-width positive lookbehind assertion).

```
    IEnumerable<string> WordWrap(string text, int width)
    {
        const string forcedBreakZonePattern = @"\n";
        const string normalBreakZonePattern = @"\s+|(?<=[-,.;])|$";

        var forcedZones = Regex.Matches(text, forcedBreakZonePattern).Cast<Match>().ToList();
        var normalZones = Regex.Matches(text, normalBreakZonePattern).Cast<Match>().ToList();

        int start = 0;

        while (start < text.Length)
        {
            var zone = 
                forcedZones.Find(z => z.Index >= start && z.Index <= start + width) ??
                normalZones.FindLast(z => z.Index >= start && z.Index <= start + width);

            if (zone == null)
            {
                yield return text.Substring(start, width);
                start += width;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return text.Substring(start, zone.Index - start);
                start = zone.Index + zone.Length;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wonder what will happen if I will provide it a string with out any spaces :)

Comment: @HellBaby It just breaks it at the specified width when there are no spaces. That's what the if zone == null block is for. That was the desired behavior, for my use case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been working on creating some abstractions that imitate window-like features in a performance- and memory-sensitive console context.

To this end I had to implement word-wrapping functionality without any unnecessary string allocations.

The following is what I managed to simplify it into. This method:

- preserves new-lines in the input string,
- allows you to specify what characters it should break on (space, hyphen, etc.),
- returns the start indices and lengths of the lines via `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringSegment` struct instances (but it's very simple to replace this struct with your own, or append directly to a `StringBuilder`).

```cs
public static IEnumerable<StringSegment> WordWrap(string input, int maxLineLength, char[] breakableCharacters)
{
    int lastBreakIndex = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        var nextForcedLineBreak = lastBreakIndex + maxLineLength;

        // If the remainder is shorter than the allowed line-length, return the remainder. Short-circuits instantly for strings shorter than line-length.
        if (nextForcedLineBreak >= input.Length)
        {
            yield return new StringSegment(input, lastBreakIndex, input.Length - lastBreakIndex);
            yield break;
        }

        // If there are native new lines before the next forced break position, use the last native new line as the starting position of our next line.
        int nativeNewlineIndex = input.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine, nextForcedLineBreak, maxLineLength);
        if (nativeNewlineIndex > -1)
        {
            nextForcedLineBreak = nativeNewlineIndex + Environment.NewLine.Length + maxLineLength;
        }

        // Find the last breakable point preceding the next forced break position (and include the breakable character, which might be a hypen).
        var nextBreakIndex = input.LastIndexOfAny(breakableCharacters, nextForcedLineBreak, maxLineLength) + 1;

        // If there is no breakable point, which means a word is longer than line length, force-break it.
        if (nextBreakIndex == 0)
        {
            nextBreakIndex = nextForcedLineBreak;
        }

        yield return new StringSegment(input, lastBreakIndex, nextBreakIndex - lastBreakIndex);

        lastBreakIndex = nextBreakIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a great solution, for the memory handling and I wanted to keep all the breakable characters (except newline, which is nicely kept as breaking, but not easy to know it was a newline char). I did add some logic though. If a segment is exactly max length before a break char, then you're keeping the break char on the line, resulting in max+1. In that case, I subtract one from nextBreakIndex.
 See https://dotnetfiddle.net/ps9sep

Answer (score 0):

If you want another newline to make text look-like paragraphs, just use Replace method of your String object.

```
        var str =
            "Line 1\n" +
            "Line 2\n" +
            "Line 3\n";

        Console.WriteLine("Before:\n" + str);

        str = str.Replace("\n", "\n\n");

        Console.WriteLine("After:\n" + str);
```