# Regular expression for one or more white spaces, tabs or newlines

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently using this regex replace statement:

```
currentLine = Regex.Replace(currentLine, " {1,} \t \n", @" ");
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

I need a regular expression, that replaces white space(s), new line characters and/or tabs with a single white space.

Are there any other space characters, that I should have in mind ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c

Comment: your regex will lookfor one or more space followed by tab then space then a new line. You should use or (|) operator if you want to match one of them. Something like "\s+|\t+|\n+"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For all whitespace use:

```
\s+
```

for specific chars you can use:

```
[ \t\n]+
```

Other space characters are `\r` and `\f`

Answer (score 4):

```
currentLine = Regex.Replace(currentLine, @"\s+", " ");
```

`+` is shorthand for 1 or more and `\s` is "whitespace".

Comment: It should be noted that `\s` matches `Unicode` only in `c#`.  That may or may not be an issue.

Comment: @EvaldasB, @ is for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c