# Replace Contiguous Instance of a String in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I replace contiguous substring of a string in C#?
For example, the string

`"<p>The&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quick&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;fox</p>"`

will be converted to

`"<p>The&nbsp;quick&nbsp;fox</p>"`

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: How many characters is the minimum repetition length?

Comment: It wasn't necessarily of variable length. I just want to replace all contiguous &nbsp; to just one;

Comment: @Thomas I tried google but i can't find the right keywords, and all the results seem to be for contiguous single characters only using regex

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)

Comment: @Gusdor this is not a duplicate because what I am trying to replace here are strings, not single characters, they have different approach in Regex

Answer (score 3):

Use the below regex

```
@"(.+)\1+"
```

`(.+)` captures the group of characters  and matches also the following `\1+` one or more same set of characters.

And then replace the match with `$1`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tJ4cY2/1)

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(.+)\1+", "$1");
```

Comment: I don't get why (.+) matches exactly &nbsp and nothing else in this example, could you explain that? (I verified it with a regex tester - i just don't understand why it behaves like it does)

Comment: it actually replaces all contiguous strings

Comment: how if i only want to replace contiguous &nbsp;

Comment: then use this `(&nbsp;)\1+` regex and replace the match by `$1` , https://regex101.com/r/tJ4cY2/2

Comment: Or forget the backreference entirely... `(&nbsp;)+`. `+` is already one-or-more and greedy.

Comment: note that your regex also replaces `&nbsp;` with `&nbsp;` . It decreases the performance little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this simple one is enough:

```
(&nbsp;){2,}
```

and replace with `$1` (`&nbsp;` that's captured in first parenthesized group)

See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gM5hR9/4)

---

To check, if a substring is followed by itself, also can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?:(&nbsp;)(?=\1))+
```

and replace with empty. See [test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gM5hR9/1)

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the original string `s` and the substring `subString`:

```
    var s = "<p>The&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quick&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;fox</p>";
    var subString = "&nbsp;";
```

I'd prefer this instead of a regex, much more readable:

```
    var subStringTwice = subString + subString;

    while (s.Contains(subStringTwice))
    {
        s = s.Replace(subStringTwice, subString);
    }
```

Another possible solution with better performance:

```
    var elements = s.Split(new []{subString}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    s = string.Join(subString, elements);
    // This part is only needed when subString can appear at the start or the end of s
    if (result != "")
    {
        if (s.StartsWith(subString)) result = subString + result;
        if (s.EndsWith(subString)) result = result + subString;                
    }
```

Comment: To my regex loving eyes, this is only more readable if you are **not familiar with regex**. Algorithmically speaking, this could also be much more expensive but that is barely worth mentioning.

Comment: Yup... repeated string replace is expensive, and the split method fails if the substring appears at the start or end of the input.