# Split string only after the first word which is separated by multiple spaces

Tags: c#

I would like to split a string only after the first word which has more than two spaces b/w them. For example:

```
string myString = "AAAA AAA DDD    BBBB BBB BBB        CCCCCCCC";
```

I want to split it into these:

```
"AAAA AAA DDD"   
"BBBB BBB BBB        CCCCCCCC"
```

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried till now? BTW: Your criteria to split string into mutiple "words" are not clear.

Comment: I tried this var array = myString.Split(new string[] {"  "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: If this the case: "AAA BB   CCC     DDDD", I want this string into two separate words like "AAA BB" and "CCC     DDDD"

Comment: `"CCCCCCCC"` is more than two spaces away from `"BBBB BBB BBB"` - shouldn't that become it's own entry after splitting?

Comment: Yes that should be.

Comment: Ugly, but: `myString.Replace("  ", "|").Split(new char {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Substring` is the simplest way:

```
string myString = "AAAA AAA DDD    BBBB BBB BBB        CCCCCCCC";
int splitIndex = myString.IndexOf("  ");
if (splitIndex > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myString.Substring(0, splitIndex).Trim());
    Console.WriteLine(myString.Substring(splitIndex).Trim());
}
else
    throw new FormatException();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string myString = "AAAA AAA DDD    BBBB BBB BBB        CCCCCCCC";   
Regex searchTerm = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);


var splitedData = searchTerm.Replace(myString, "|").Split(new string[]{"|"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach(var d in splitedData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", d);
}
```

Result:

```
AAAA AAA DDD
BBBB BBB BBB
CCCCCCCC
```

My solution is based on this: [How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)