# Unable to remove unnecessary whitespace before Textbox submission to Database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I have been trying to remove duplicate whitespace from textbox before the data is submitted to database. I have tried `TRIM()` function in MySQL, like

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES TRIM(('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "'))";
```

it did not work. I also tried this

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("  ", " ");
```

I added above code to the submission button which works but it only removes whitespace if it appears twice, as in, double space. In a case where the user input more than two spaces, how do I implement it?

For example: `"Hello    World"` should be submitted as `"Hello World"`

Comment: Use Trim() : textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Trim();

Comment: Never, ever build an executable string from raw user input. Please search for "SQL injection attack" to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
stextBox1 = textBox1.Text;

RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);     
textBox1.Text = regex.Replace(stextBox1 , " ");
```

Got is from [How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)

You need to add the line:
    `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` under `using System;`
below is an example in c# that works:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string stextBox1 = textBox1.Text;

            RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
            Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
            textBox1.Text = regex.Replace(stextBox1, " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add Trim to remove all white space from beginning and end, its only in the middle the OP want to collapse multiple to one.

Comment: Thanks @zip. This doesn't work. I am having lots of errors. Just started programming, not good at regular expression. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

try this code with regular expression :

```
        string str = textBox1.Text;
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "");
```

Comment: you have to keep a space char ```str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ");```

Answer (score 0):

This should result is what you want to achieve:

```
string str = textBox1.Text;
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ");
```